# Delete page permanently

Tags: sharepoint

I deleted sharepoint page  which is based on page layout through browser by going siteactions-->managing content and structure--> pages--> selected the page--> delete(by right clicking).

But when I see in the content database still the page is there. Basically I want to delete the content type which I could not delete as it is being used by a page. I am getting "Content type is in use"

Is there one have solution for this. Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is not actually deleted, but moved to the SharePoint site's Recycle bin. Delete it from there and you should be good to go.

Big P.S.: do not mess with the content database(s), if you do you are not supported anymore, meaning you can't call ms support with a (free) service call to fix things. They'll send the consultant and those don't come cheap...

Comment: The content type is in use.at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.DeleteFromWeb(SPContentTypeId id, String strName) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentTypeCollection.Delete(SPContentTypeId id) 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContentType.Delete() 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageContentTypePage.DeleteContentType() 
 at Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ManageContentTypePage.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String )  
Thanks Colin.I deleted all the pages(cleared the recycle bin) and still I am getting the same error as I mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

The backing database for SharePoint is SQL server. Feel like going duck hunting?